# How can I simulate a specific time for a program?

Tags: c#, .net

The question is kinda hard to understand but what I'm trying to do is to launch a program and make that program think that the system clock is "some other date and time" and not actually change the system time. How can I do this programmatically using C#?

P.S: I can't alter the program I launch in any way.

EDIT: I just realised that the program checks the time only once after ~4-6 seconds of startup. So I will just change the system clock for 10 seconds and restore it back! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I think that changing the system time is going to be 100000 times easier and quicker

Comment: I don't want to interrupt any other programs running that depend on the system clock.

Comment: If you're talking about changing the time for a specific program  (and no others), it's not possible.

Comment: Instead of programming a solution around this, can't you run the prog in a VM with a different date/time?

Comment: Trying to rephrase: you have a program that queries system time. You can't change system time, and you can't change the program. Your only bet would be to intercept the call to the OS - this will be a bit like writing a virus, and modern OS's typically aren't going to let you... I think you're out of luck... Curious to see if anyone can get around this conundrum!

Comment: @PeterRitchie That's exactly what I'm trying to do. ._.

Comment: I don't think you can, short of using a VM. Other than that, without giving proper reasons you're not likely to get many useful answers beyond "just buy a license".

Comment: @MarkusDeibel That would do perfecty fine but the machine I'm working on has severe resource limitations(it's 10 years old) so that's currently not an option.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to intercept calls to winAPI like `GetSystemTime`. C# is not the best instrument for such thing, but nothing impossible. Use any detours library that supports C#. Think of a way to modify program address space (remote thread, `WriteProcessMemory`, filter DLL).

That is a very general idea of where you may find the solution.

Though if you will ask how to intercept program calls to OS, you will hardly get any answers here, at least if you show no own efforts.

Comment: `GetSystemTime` is not the only function to get time. `OP` should check for time-related API calls on the application first.

Comment: Hmm... I thought that there would be an easier way. I already know that I should change API calls but I just wanted a easy way. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @fardjad, I know it is not the only, I've said 'like' :)
OP, there is no easy way I know of. The system does not return current time on per-process basis.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what date/time functions your application uses, you can investigate which system calls those CLR methods use. Once you know, you can test your software in an environment where those calls are intercepted, presumably giving "fake" responses to e.g. `DateTime.Now` in .NET.

There are utilities that do this for you, for example http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html

I don't know if the specific system calls intercepted by that utility is the ones used by the framework to give for example `DateTime.Now`

Answer (score 1):

This is the old question but my answer will probably help someone.
What we do in our project is to use interface like this:

```
interface IDateTime
{
    DateTime Now();
    ....
}
```

Then you use IDateTime instead of regular DateTime just everywhere and IoC to get instance of IDateTime.

So, as result you can create any implementation of Now().
Really helpful when writing unit tests.